# How to extract unique values WITH NAs

Tags: r, unique

I need to extract unique values from a column, but I need to keep NAs...when I use unique() it only returns values different from NAs...is there a way to filter unique values, keeping NAs?

My columns consist of article's DOIs, but there are some NAs within it. I'm using unique() in order to account for duplicates articles in my sample, but if it keeps on ignoring NAs, then it automatically excludes the ones which haven't provided a DOI...

I've seen similar questions here, but I wasn't able to solve my problem with the solutions from other posts...

[image: my column]

in the function's documentation, I get:

> Missing values ("NA") are regarded as equal, numeric and complex ones differing from NaN; character strings will be compared in a “common encoding”; for details, see match (and duplicated) which use the same concept.

What should I do?

Comment: When you say ignoring `NA`s, are you getting a single `NA` elements as in `unique(c(1, 2, NA, 2, NA, 3))#
[1]  1  2 NA  3`

Comment: Do you need `subset(dat, !duplicated(D1)|is.na(D1))`

Comment: Oh, thanks very much! This subset seems to be working just fine! ps: when I said "ignorning", I meant that the unique() wasn't returning me the NA values, only the non-Nas, but your solution worked just fine! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`unique` on the data column returns only the unique values including the `NA`, thus if there are 100 NAs, it returns a single `NA`.  We could correct that by using `duplicated` with `is.na`

```
subset(dat, !duplicated(D1)|is.na(D1))
```

`!duplicated(D1)` - returns TRUE for all unique values and FALSE for duplicates, `is.na` returns TRUE for all NA and FALSE for non-NA.  Using `|`, returns TRUE if either one of the conditions are TRUE, thus the logical expression returns TRUE for unique elements as well as NA elements which is used in `subset` to filter the rows

Comment: Thank you! There's something odd happening: I have in total 1118 rows. When I sum the number of Nas in my DOI row, I get 176 rows. When I apply unique(), it returns me 570 values. When I use the subset syntax you've instructed me, I don't get 746 rows, but rather 745...isn't this weird?

Comment: @LarissaCury can you check the number of NAs in the subset data i.e. `d2 <- subset(dat, !duplicated(D1)|is.na(D1)); sum(is.na(d2$D1))`

Comment: @LarissaCury that can be explained.  You get 570 values, which also include a single NA with unique, whereas with duplicated, you get all the NAs, thus there is a difference in 1

Comment: Something interesting happened, when I subset, I can see the Nas in my column, but if I count it, as you've asked me, I get 0                                                                        d2 <- subset(data, !duplicated(DI)|is.na(DI))
> View(d2)
> sum(is.na(d2$D1))
[1] 0

Comment: @LarissaCury that seems strange.  Can you do this on a fresh R session

Comment: @LarissaCury is the column name correct i.e. is it `DI` or `D1`?

Comment: ohhh, yeah, it's with an "i", I just copied and pasted, that's why I got 0,                              
> sum(is.na(d2$DI))
[1] 176

Comment: @LarissaCury R is case-sensitive as well.  Although there is a partial matching in efffect with `$`, it still won't work when you specify `D1` instead of just `D`

Comment: now I guess that everything is working just fine! I have a total of 1118 observations. When I use unique(), I get 570 (therefore, it means that I have 569 non-duplicates, right?), using the subset, I get 745, 176 (my NA count) + 569 (unique), right? thank you!! Not couting the NAs, I had 197 duplicates, right?